# Return Intersected Date Range from a List of Dates

Tags: c#, datetime, date-range

I have a list of Calendar objects which contain ParentId, StartDate and EndDate which represent breaks in work shifts. There could be many shifts operating in an area at any time, each with different breaks.

I need to be able to get the date range where they intersect so that I can determine when there is no-one currently working in each area.

For example, if I have the following shift breaks:

```
new Calendar { ParentId = 1, StartDate = 2017-06-18 11:50:00, EndDate = 2017-06-18 12:20:00 };
new Calendar { ParentId = 2, StartDate = 2017-06-18 12:10:00, EndDate = 2017-06-18 12:40:00 };    
new Calendar { ParentId = 3, StartDate = 2017-06-18 12:15:00, EndDate = 2017-06-18 12:45:00 };
```

then the intersection time I need to return is 12:15:00 - 12:20:00 as that is the only time that the area has nobody present.

I've tried with the Time Period For .NET library, but that only tells me that intersections exist, not what the range of the intersection is.

Just to be clear, I don't want to know if intersections or overlaps exist, I need to know the ranges where they occur.

[image]

Comment: The best way is to sort by StartDate.  You should be checking for when no-one is working which is when row(x-1) EndDate < row(x) StartDate.  So instead of using breaks you must use working times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var cals = new []
{
    new { ParentId = 1, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 11:50:00"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 12:20:00") },
    new { ParentId = 2, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 12:10:00"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 12:40:00") },
    new { ParentId = 3, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 12:15:00"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-06-18 12:45:00") },
};

var intersection =
    cals
        .Aggregate((c0, c1) => new
        {
            ParentId = -1,
            StartDate = c0.StartDate > c1.StartDate ? c0.StartDate : c1.StartDate,
            EndDate = c0.EndDate < c1.EndDate ? c0.EndDate : c1.EndDate
        });
```

It gave me:

[image: intersection]

Comment: Perfect answer, you've saved my bacon, thanks very much Enigmativity. Hadn't even considered the aggregate function. Such a simple elegant solution